# Xpath get nth element

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, selector

I'm trying to pull the death age from this html using xpath. The issue im having is that it doesn't have a class name or selector to grab the info. Is there a way to grab the 3rd class stat and then inside of that grab the 3rd a href and inside of that grab the age which is after the span?

This is what I have so far but it's not working

```
=IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class='stat'][3]")
```

The html code:

```
<div class="is-flex">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
    <div class="stat box">
    <i class="icn icn-birthday"></i>
    <h6> Birthday </h6>
<a href="/february26.html"><span class="hidden-sm">February</span><span class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg">Feb</span> 26</a>, <a href="/year/1932.html">1932</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
<div class="stat box">
<i class="icn icn-birthplace"></i>
<h6>Birthplace</h6>
Kingsland,
<a href="/birthplace/arkansas.html"> AR </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
<div class="stat box">
<i class="icn icn-age"></i>
<h6>Death Date</h6><a href="/deceased/day/september12.html">Sep 12</a>, <a href="/deceased/2003.html">2003</a> (<a href="/deceased/age/71.html"><span class="hidden-sm">age </span>71</a>)
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
<div class="stat box">
<i class="icn icn-horiscope"></i>
<h6>Birth Sign</h6><a href="/astrology/pisces.html">Pisces</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath expression:

```
//div[@class='stat box'][1]/a[3]/text()
```

should output:

```
71
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the age value with the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
=IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[contains(@class,'stat') and contains(h6,'Death Date')]/a[contains(@href,'/deceased/age')]/span/following::text()")
```

which returns `71` including some spaces.
To get rid of the leading and trailing spaces, use

```
=IMPORTXML(B3,"normalize-space(//div[contains(@class,'stat') and contains(h6,'Death Date')]/a[contains(@href,'/deceased/age')]/span/following::text())")
```